# HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported when doing return "redirect:*.*" in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In spring MVC...
I have to reload a page after the record is updated. So in the action method I am returning String and in return I am returning

```
 return "redirect:/recordList";
```

When but it is giving the exception on the page

```
 HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported
```

There is no exception coming on the logs.

My controller method looks like

```
    @RequestMapping(value= "/recordList", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView getAssetListForUser(@RequestParam("ldapId") String ldapId,
        final HttpServletRequest request){
```

Also, because I need the value if ldapId in the controller method, I am binding it in the calling method like this

```
     request.setAttribute("ldapId", assetAssetEmp.getAssetEmpId());
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `/recordList` controller method only supports `RequestMethod.POST`.
hence you're getting the 405 GET Method not allowed error, since the redirect will issue a GET request.

to solve for it, try to give a GET version of your controller action. (the assetlist method) so that once the update happens, the asset list of the user can be returned via the GET method.

Comment: Changing it is now giving HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported when I call it directly from the action on submit of jsp. :(

Comment: How then about allowing GET and POST? `method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET}`

Comment: removed the RequestMethod.POST altogether. Now it works fine.

Comment: so whats the default behavior of  controller method? is it GET or POST? or it gets changes depending upon the type parameter we pass in form or ajax?

Answer (score 0):

The `@RequestMapping` annotation is your way to specify when your method is going to be called in an annotated controller. The `RequestMethod.GET` and `RequestMethod.POST` arguments allow you to respond to the specific `HTTP` request type.

providing `method = RequestMethod.POST` to controller method actually making method to accept only `HTTP POST` requests.

[RequestMethod](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMethod.html)